# Chain promises without original caller

Tags: javascript, promise, chaining

I'm calling the background script to execute stuff from the popup window - problem is the popup window might get closed and then part won't execute.

```
initialize().then(()=> doOtherStuff());
```

Any method to make sure this chain of promises executes without the original caller?

Comment: No. Move this code into the background script and then send a message from your popup so the background script does the processing.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "background script", "popup window" and "original caller".

Comment: @jmargolsvt Are you sure that this is no specific to extensions? I'm not understanding a word without that context.